# How to keep an slide menu always open?

Tags: javascript

I´m using this tumblr theme:
http://flataura.tumblr.com/

And I want the slide menu at the right of the text "Flaty" that opens when you click on it, to be always opened. Is there any solution for this?

Here is the javascript of that slide:
http://static.tumblr.com/ssdtkch/gT6nanpl7/pageslide.js

Thanks!

Comment: does this actually have anything to do with java?

Comment: I think it does, I think I need to modify the .js file to do this but I don´t know how!

Comment: Java and javascript are different languages @LTart

Comment: I edited the question, thanks @GtoXic and Chris for pointing that!

Comment: well, what the script does is move the `body` 281px(in my case) to the right with the `style="margin-left: 281px;"` and sets the `sidebar`'s styles to `style="left:0; display: block;"`. If you want it to be static, you can do that without the use of that javascript.

Comment: I think you want something like this? https://mega.nz/#!eMwjBara!g6sGzg9LGMj8J79vtwRDJ8ZpO5z7trwT4jE-2_cmoVY it is a zip file, containing the files of the websites, a little edited

Comment: @Evochrome Thank you so much for this! I will try with this to see what happens, will be great to learn a bit more. Thank you again!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seeing from a comment that you are familiar enough to edit the CSS. Add this to the bottom of your CSS and it should show the menu AND hide the button that animates the show/hide:

```
body {
    margin-left: 281px;
}

div#side {
    display: block !important;
    left: 0;
    right: auto;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    height: 100%;
    z-index: 1000000;
    overflow-y: scroll;
    width: 280px;
    background-color: rgba(33,63,82, 0.93);
    border-right: 1px solid #213f52;
}

a.open-sidebar.nav-button {
    display: none;
}
```

Comment: That´s awesome! it worked like a charm. Thank you!! as I´m new I can´t upvote your answer but thank you again!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there are ways to do this. But since it doesn't seem like you're very familiar with websites, the solution is too complicated via StackOverflow. Let me know if you would like to get in contact, and I can walk you through this.

In a nutshell, the #side element contains that left bit, but is always hidden. The #pageslide element is what gets shown, and as soon as you click the first time, the contents of #side get cloned into #pageslide. Then, jQuery (Javascript) is used to animate the transition, introducing a margin to your entire body element.

All of this can be overridden, but it is several steps. If you know a web developer, that information above should get them started. Otherwise, let me know if you want to get in contact.

Good luck!

Comment: It's actually fairly simple, but OP probably doesn't have very much experience in webdeveloping.

Comment: Thanks for your comment! as @Evochrome said I just only know the veeery basic of coding. One user posted a link with modified codes so I will be trying with that. Thanks a lot for your response!